# Usage of ":=" and ":-" in shell script while exporting variable

Tags: shell

In shell scripts we use

```
export VAR1=${VAR1:-KK}

export DATE=${DATE:=$(cat ${DATEDIR}/today_date)}
```

I have seen this in many scripts.

Please explain me or refer a good link for why `:-` and `:=` is being used and where exactly should it be used.

Comment: Have you read the section of the bash man page on parameter substitution?

Comment: Using `:=` on the RHS of an assignment to the same variable seems redundant to me. Either `export DATE=${DATE:-...}` or `export ${DATE:=...}` would work the same, I think.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Parameter expansion` section of the `bash` man page:

> ${parameter:-word}
>             **Use Default Values**.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter
>   is substituted.
>
> ${parameter:=word}
>             **Assign  Default  Values**.   If  parameter  is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter.  The value of
>   parameter is then substituted.  Positional parameters and special
>   parameters may not be assigned to in this way.

There are many other options during parameter expansion, see the man page for all of them.