# What does colon. hyphen and none mean in bash script expression?

Tags: bash, shell

What does this mean in bash scripting:

```
local cluster=${1:-none}
```

looks like assignment of first argument, but what is other code for?

Comment: [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `${parameter:-word}` If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted. Note: it's not bash specific but for all [POSIX shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909081/shell-what-is-the-purpose-of-var-when-var-is-unset-or-null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806949/usage-of-and-in-shell-script-while-exporting-variable/15807096#15807096

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893336/replace-empty-element-in-bash-array/41893887#41893887